# Breaker box that is full

Tags: circuit-breaker, electrical-panel, breaker-box

My box is full and I have a gas water heater and trying to switch to a electric tank. Could I just take out two of my 110s and replace it w a 220v for the new tank.?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that there are no service capacity constraints, you have a few options:

1. Replace some of the breakers with tandem breakers.  These essentially double the density of each slot.  These breakers come in a variety of configurations of both 120/240V and combos with both.  This is the easiest of options for a do-it-yourselfer to complete.
2. Install a sub-panel. You would relocate a number of circuits from the current box to a new sub-panel.
3. Replace the entire breaker panel with a larger panel. This is the most difficult of the three options and sometimes requires the utility to disconnect your service in order to complete this.

As always, contact a licensed electrician if you are unsure of how to safely make these modifications.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on more than space to do it. Is your incoming service adequate to power an electric water heater (EWH) and the other things you use electricity to do? An EWH is a very significant load - if your service is not of adequate size, you may manage to trip the main breaker...

And, of course, you'll presumably want to relocate those 120V circuits somewhere that they continue to get power, rather than permanently turn off some of your lights and outlets so that you can install an EWH. So you'll want a sub-panel, or a larger main panel, unless your panel is listed to use dual-circut breakers in enough spaces that are not already using them so that you can replace 4 120V single breakers with 2 120V dual breakers and the 240V EWH breaker.

Depending on your incoming service, you may ALSO need a service upgrade (from the pole to the house, and upgrading the main panel), which might (price-tag-wise) make sticking with gas for water heating look good.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove two breakers, whatever was powered by those circuits will no longer work.  You cannot power the existing circuit *and* the heater, from the same breaker(s).

You may be able to switch some of the existing breakers over to tandem breakers, but only if your panel supports them, and you're not already using tandems.

Installing a secondary panel, might also be an option. However, without a lot more details, it's not possible to give a more detailed answer.

As it sounds like you're not very experienced with electrical work, it might be best to have a local licensed Electrician do the work.